# Как объединить ts файлы в один? Java

Tags: java, видео

есть много файлов формата ts,как их объединить в один при помощи Java?

Comment: Вам вот прям java нужна? ffmpeg умеет это в одну команду

Comment: Чисто из любопытства.Спасибо за ffmpeg,уже есть java обертки над ней